# How to make rules of CrawlSpider context-sensitive?

Tags: scrapy

I notice that, the `rule` of `CrawlSpider` extract urls on every none-leaf pages.
Can I enable `rule` only when current page meets some condition (for example: url matches a regex)?

I have two pages:

---

```
-------------------Page A-------------------
Page URL: http://www.site.com/pattern-match.html
--------------------------------------------

- [link](http://should-extract-this)
- [link](http://should-extract-this)
- [link](http://should-extract-this)

--------------------------------------------
```

---

```
--------------------Page B--------------------
Page URL: http://www.site.com/pattern-not-match.html
-----------------------------------------------

- [link](http://should-not-extract-this)
- [link](http://should-not-extract-this)
- [link](http://should-not-extract-this)

-----------------------------------------------
```

---

So, the rule should only extract urls from PageA. How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: The question is not clear.  Are you looking for a certain rule pattern? `Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('pattern-match', ), deny=('pattern-not-match', )))`

Comment: @agstudy I'm looking for a neat way to make `Rule` support context (current page on which `SgmlLinkExtractor` extracts urls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a dirty way to inject `response` to `rule`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.http import Request, HtmlResponse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

import inspect

class MyCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if not isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
            return
        seen = set()
        for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [l for l in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response) if l not in seen]
            if links and rule.process_links:
                links = rule.process_links(links)
            seen = seen.union(links)
            for link in links:
                r = Request(url=link.url, callback=self._response_downloaded)
                r.meta.update(rule=n, link_text=link.text)

                # ***>>> HACK <<<***
                # pass `response` as additional argument to `process_request`

                fun = rule.process_request
                if not hasattr(fun, 'nargs'):
                    fun.nargs = len(inspect.getargs(fun.func_code).args)
                if fun.nargs==1:
                    yield fun(r)
                elif fun.nargs==2:
                    yield fun(r, response)
                else:
                    raise Exception('too many arguments')
```

Try it out:

```
def process_request(request, response):

    if 'magick' in response.url:
        return request

class TestSpider(MyCrawlSpider):

    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['test.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.test.com']

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a'), callback='parse_item', process_request=process_request),
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        print response.url
```